# how to add no. of rows based on value of a select box in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

what i am trying to do is, i want to add a certain numbers of rows to my table based on value of select box. i have one input type select box which gives the value and when a button is clicked, the value of select box's (number of rows) should be added to my table in below format:

Table Heading:

**Day** | **Night_at** | **Title** | **Itinerary** | **Hotel_id** | **Roomtype_id**

Table Row (should be added):

day-1 | `<select box for nite_at>`| `<input for title>` | `<text area for itinerary` | `<select hotel_id` | `<select roomtype_id`

my code: #html part:

```html
<div class="row">    
<div class="col-md-4 padding-top-10">
<div class="input-group text-black">
<span class="input-group-addon">Days: </span>
<select name="days" id="days" class="form-control">
<option>--Select</option>
<option value="3">3 Days</option>
<option value="4">4 Days</option>
<option value="5">5 Days</option>
<option value="6">6 Days</option>
<option value="7">7 Days</option>
<option value="8">8 Days</option>
<option value="9">9 Days</option>
<option value="10">10 Days</option>
<option value="11">11 Days</option>
<option value="12">12 Days</option>
<option value="13">13 Days</option>
<option value="14">14 Days</option>
<option value="15">15 Days</option>
<option value="16">16 Days</option>
<option value="17">17 Days</option>
<option value="18">18 Days</option>
<option value="19">19 Days</option>
<option value="20">20 Days</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 padding-top-10">
<button class="btn btn-success" name="create" id="create">Create</button>
</div>
</div>
```

i jst need the js code for my html code to work. any kind of help is appriciated. Thnx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your table has a `<tbody>` tag with the id "mytbody" the following will the number of rows based on the value of the select

```
$('#create').click(function()
{
    for(i = 0, i < $('#days').val(), i++)
    {
        $('#mytbody').append( $('<tr>') );
    }
});
```

You can then append the table row that has been created to add the content you want